# Centralizing actions of a program

Tags: c#

I have a program that needs to perform some actions from various forms. I want to keep the actions in a centralized space. Each action has its own class that is derived from a interface.

Each action is only instantiated once, but is used on various places, like contextmenu, ribbon, toolbar and so on.

I have the following code working, and I want to get rid of the typeof in when making a list. I want to have strong typing, no reflection and the possibility to refactor.

Can this be done more efficient?

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ActionManager actionManager = new ActionManager();

            List<SomeInterface> listA = actionManager.CreateList(typeof(Do_A), typeof(Do_B));
            List<SomeInterface> listB = actionManager.CreateList(typeof(Do_A), typeof(Do_B));
        }
    }

    public class ActionManager
    {
        private Dictionary<Type, SomeInterface> instantiatedActions = new Dictionary<Type, SomeInterface>();

        public List<SomeInterface> CreateList(params Type[] actions)
        {
            List<SomeInterface> theList = new List<SomeInterface>();

            foreach (Type type in actions)
            {
                if(!instantiatedActions.ContainsKey(type))
                {
                    instantiatedActions.Add(type, (SomeInterface)Activator.CreateInstance(type));
                }
                theList.Add(instantiatedActions[type]);
            }

            return theList;
        }
    }

    public interface SomeInterface
    {
    }

    public class Do_A : SomeInterface
    {
    }

    public class Do_B : SomeInterface
    {
    }

    public class Do_C : SomeInterface
    {
    }
```

Comment: Also, `SomeInterface` and `Do_A/B/C` classes aren't likely to fly over at CR. Hypothetical example code is off-topic for Code Review.

Comment: This looks an awful lot like a Command pattern, I'd suggest reading over how WPF uses Commands. I'm not sure what UI you are using, but its worth looking at: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752308%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @Ron Beyer: ICommand is indeed part of SomeInterface :) But there are a lot more things in there. Glyphs, Displaynames etc. 
What I am trying to achieve looks a bit like the BarManager from DevExpress, where all the actions of a program are kept in a central place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create expressions that return your type if the type has not already been seen.  This would allow you to keep your strong typing and would enforce that only SomeInterface implementations would be allowed to be passed in.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ActionManager actionManager = new ActionManager();

    List<SomeInterface> listA = actionManager.CreateList<SomeInterface>(
            () => new Do_A(), () => new Do_B());
    List<SomeInterface> listB = actionManager.CreateList<SomeInterface>(
            () => new Do_A(), () => new Do_B());
}

public class ActionManager
{
    private Dictionary<Type, SomeInterface> instantiatedActions = 
            new Dictionary<Type, SomeInterface>();

    public List<SomeInterface> CreateList<T>(params Expression<Func<T>>[] actions)
    {
        List<SomeInterface> theList = new List<SomeInterface>();

        foreach (var action in actions)
        {
            var type = GetObjectType<T>(action);
            if(!instantiatedActions.ContainsKey(type))
            {
                instantiatedActions.Add(type, (SomeInterface)action.Compile().Invoke());
            }
            theList.Add(instantiatedActions[type]);
        }

        return theList;
    }

    private static Type GetObjectType<T>(Expression<Func<T>> expr)
    {
        if ((expr.Body.NodeType == ExpressionType.Convert) ||
            (expr.Body.NodeType == ExpressionType.ConvertChecked))
        {
            var unary = expr.Body as UnaryExpression;
            if (unary != null)
                return unary.Operand.Type;
        }
        return expr.Body.Type;
    }
}
```

The caveat is needing to both compile the expression to invoke it and needing to return the type from the expression tree.  However, per your comment, it ensure lazy instantiation only if the type has not already been seen, as well as guaranteeing type safety.

Comment: Very nifty solution. Calling the list look a bit ugly, but it does what I asked for.

Comment: I wouldn't call the syntax pretty :).  But it does give you your strong typing and lazy instantiation and the syntax isn't too much more verbose than what you had in the first place.

Comment: I side effect seems to be that the constructor for the various classes can take parameters. I like it :)

Comment: @JvdBerg That is one distinctive advantage, since if you were invoking this from an IoC Kernel you could be very specific about how your objects get created and with exactly what dependencies, which I consider a good DI example.